# I've upvoted 100 answers; why don't I have the Sportsmanship badge?

Tags: support, badges, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

The description of the Sportsmanship badge is:

> Up voted 100 competing answers

In the bottom section of [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674374/mithunsatheesh) you can see that I've cast 140 votes for answers, and 38 of my total post votes were downvotes, so even if all 38 were on answers I've still upvoted 102 answers. Why haven't I gotten the Sportsmanship badge yet?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to upvote 100 *competing* answers, not just 100 answers in general. It means you upvoted 100 answers on questions where you also provided an answer (and your answer has a positive score, to try and avoid cheating). The point is to encourage people not to avoid upvoting good answers just because they want their answer to be at the top. See also the [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) and [Vote Early, Vote Often](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)

Answer (score 6):

It needs to be on a *competing* answer--one that is competing with one of your answers for the "accepted" tick.

Here are all the competing answers:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/38592/how-close-am-i-to-the-sportsmanship-badge

Enter your userid(674374) and run the query.

There are only 11 competing answers in your case, and you may or may not have voted for them. So you're still a long way off :/

Answer (score 1):

So every single one of your upvotes was cast on a **competing** answer?

The badge is not for casting 100 upvotes in general. Those upvotes have to be for answers that are on questions you have also answered. That's what a competing answer is.